# Ajax Currency Rates

Tags: .net, ajax, asp-classic

I am after a script to show live currency rates from Israel ILS to USD, GBP and EUR on a page, this is only going to be text so there is no need for an amount or form as it is only the value of 1 ILS.

Thanks Robbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question isn't very clear so here goes my answer:

jquery $.ajax() is going to be the 'script' you want. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "http://url_to_data_feed",

  success: function(data){
    $('#someDiv').text(data); //Do work here to show the data
  }
});
```

If you're asking for specific services that offer the data feed then you need to google a bit because most charge you. http://www.oanda.com/currency-data/exchange-rate-feed/